# Flat tire right after replacing all tires - what could be the cause?

Tags: tires

We just had all 4 tires replaced, a week after we got a flat tire.
In the past several years not a single flat tire.

The cost of each tire was $55 (with labor I paid $409). The car is a Honda Civic 2007 Hybrid. The tire model says LEAO / LION SPORT GP.

The Mechanics said he put air and he does not find any leaks, he did put the tire in water and no bubbles came out. We have been driving the car for a few days now, and so far there is no sign of any leaks.

I should also mention that I heard some noises right after replacing the tires, and I checked and did not see any issue with them, and only after a week, suddenly a flat tire.

I'm not an expert about cars but my logic mind assumes that the tire was not fully or correctly assembled when replacing the tires. Could that be the cause?

**UPDATE - 8 MONTHS LATER**

Tires still have no issues. This means it has to be incorrect first assembly, which was fixed on the second assembly.

Comment: What caused the flat? Was there a puncture, or is it leaking where it seals with the rim?

Comment: The quality you mention is probably proportional to the price you paid, as above puncture or leak  and then is the question about the state of the rims - have they been damaged by hitting the kerb? or are they rusty / corroded.

Comment: I concur, the reason of the flat is very important for the correct answer of your question!

Comment: Describe "weird noises"? How long time passed from change to flat? Tire can not be assembled wrong. You just push it into the rim. You still did not tell exactly where were you and what you did prior to noticing the flat. I don't understand what relevance does it have if you park your car in garage or not. For example, if you parked on a street at any point and when you came back the tire was flat. I clearly asked the events before the flat...Is it a secret? :)

Comment: Tires can certainly be "assembled wrong" and damage can occur during installation. The document you linked to has an entire section on this, titled "Fitting Damage". It contains information such as, "Tyres can also be damaged even when not in use, for example due to incorrect mounting on
the rim. The bead might be damaged while the tyre is being fitted or removed using a tyre fitting machine. Undetected fitting damage can result in the tyre failure at a later date." - http://www.bushtyres.co.uk/library/pdf/conti-tyre-damage-guide.pdf

Comment: That's because the reduced diameter of the lower-tread tires causes them to spin faster than a new one. Wheels moving at different speeds on an AWD vehicle will put the vehicle into 4-wheel lock, which can cause damage to the drive train.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unlikely to be the tyres themselves at fault - if it's not down to external causes (e.g. a nail), it's more likely to be either damage to the wheel rim stopping the tyre from sealing properly, or a dodgy valve letting the air out.

Either way, after just a week you ought to be able to take it back to the dealer who fitted the tyres and they ought to sort it for you...

Comment: I will go back to the mechanic, and will report back what he find.

Comment: I don't want to waste more time on this, this is my favorable answer, maybe I just need to let go, and assume the mechanic did assemble the tire correctly the second time. If any issues arise with this tire, I will update the question. Thank you everyone for your insights.

Answer (score 4):

I know the mechanic filling the tire back up said he didn't find any leaks, but the air had to go somewhere. Assuming that the tire was correctly inflated when they were installed, the real question is where did the air leak from? The three likely possibilities are:

**1) The valve stem**

It's possible whoever changed the tires didn't use new valve stems and/or valves. They're located in the rim of the wheel, so it's entirely possible that they were overlooked. They can become brittle and crack with age, just like tires, and should be replaced at every tire change. The valve could also be leaking, especially if it doesn't have a protective cap and has been exposed to the elements.

**2) The seal between the tire and the rim**

This is an especially high possibility if you have steel rims and/or corrosion. The corrosion will create an uneven surface that will continue to deteriorate, allowing air to escape where the surfaces meet. In either case, a lubricant such as soapy water should be used liberally when mounting the tire. This will ensure the tire slides into place smoothly without damaging the inner lip of the tire, creating a good seal.

**3) There is leak somewhere in the tire**

Maybe it's a manufacturer defect (unlikely), or maybe you were just really unlucky and got a puncture. Punctures are less likely with the thick tread of a new tire, but they're still a possibility.

Going forward you need to keep an eye on the tire and see if it's losing pressure, and at what speed. You can try spraying the tire with soapy water. Any air escaping will create bubbles and be easier to pinpoint. If the leak is slow enough that it's taking a day or two to go flat, this might not work. In that case, I'd be leaning toward the seal at the rim. If the valve stems haven't been changed, consider having them changed.

Comment: If there were any kind of defects, craks leading to leaks, the mechanic could find it. Unless your answer is based on the assumption that the mechanic made a mistake and couldn't find the leak?

Comment: If the tire went flat, and there aren't any leaks, where did the air go?

Comment: We don't know exactly how this flat occured or even what he means by flat. Did you consider maybe, he parked somewhere and comes back to find tire empty because somebody simply made a prank? Did you consider if tire was not inflated properly and with hard breaking/acceleration it slipped and lost air pressure even further? I bet there are a bunch of ways that tire can go empty that I can't imagine of. But then, the only way that you are right is if his mechanic made some mistake. Because otherwise the result from the leak check of his mechanic already makes all your suggestions implausable.

Comment: No, I didn't consider that. While it's certainly not outside the realm of possibilities, it's outside the scope of this site. People here should be expecting technical advice. "Maybe someone is playing a prank" could apply to just about every question on this site. Regarding tires spinning on rims - do you have any sources? I've never heard of a car losing tyre pressure for this reason, certainly not a car with this modest amount of power.

Comment: Prank may be outside the scope but OP may have assumed cause was tire damage. I have marks on my tires next to valves. Once I realized one had a nail and it had 1.2 bar left (the car manual says normal is 1.9) and the mark was moved only on that tire almost 180degrees. The pressure in the tire also tightens the seal to rim. An empty tire may not even make full contact with rim until inflated. If your tire is underinflated, it may even get out of rim at a tight corner or cause sudden air pressure loss. See: http://www.bushtyres.co.uk/library/pdf/conti-tyre-damage-guide.pdf Page 11

Comment: Great guide, but I'm not sure I'm following. What you're referring to isn't the primary cause of pressure loss, it's the problem getting even worse once the tire is under inflated to begin with. So the question remains, how did the tire get under inflated?

Comment: How do you know if the OP's tire was inflated to correct amount to begin with? This information was not given. You are right, only if you assume it was inflated properly from beginning. Also OP mentioned that the mechanic did not find any leaks which, if true, automatically makes your suggestions incorrect. Do you understand now? Honestly, if you still don't then it is also fine, I don't want to spend more time on this since OP provided very little information and that is the reason for the confusion.

Comment: I have no problem understanding you, beyond why you would jump to some unlikely and contrived explanations first. This is the first time you've suggested that it was never fully inflated to begin with. If you don't want to discuss this further, that's your prerogative. Remember, you are the one who felt the need to comment.

Comment: but I mentioned it :) Read my 3rd comment where I say -> "if tire was not inflated properly" <-

Comment: Maybe I was just playing a prank :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are no leaks, and if you were not driving the car when the tire went flat. The first thing comes to mind is a prank. Somebody emptied your tire! You should fill it up and keep an eye on it and see if it goes empty again.

But if it happened when you were driving, it may happen with very hard braking or acceleration if the tire pressure was too low to begin with. Many times shops put a little mark next to the valve stem to see if the tire was moving on the rim (if it moves it means it did not have a tight enough seal with rim). [Tyre damage: Causes and avoidance](http://www.bushtyres.co.uk/library/pdf/conti-tyre-damage-guide.pdf) See page 11:

```
Low tyre pressures can reduce the safety when 
negotiating corners. The tyre bead may be 
torn away from the rim and slip from the rim 
flange down into the well base. The result is a 
sudden loss of air pressure in the tyre.
```

You did not tell how your mechanic checked the tire for leaks. Is your mechanic 100% sure? or could he/she be mistaken?

Because you did not tell the exact circumstances which lead to the flat. It may be impossible to answer your question. What were you doing exactly when the flat occured? ( I will update my answer if you update your question :) )

Answer (score 1):

Throwing this out there as a possibility:  There is something jammed in your tire, but unless the tire is under load the foreign object is doing a good enough job plugging the hole.  Its stabbed in someplace hard to see, or deep enough that it isn't even visible anymore.

On the day it went flat, it happened that the tire was loaded in such a way that the hole was flexed and the foreign object was no longer a good seal. When they place this tire in a water tank, there is no load and the nail/drill bit/whatever is holding it shut.