# Two flat tires after getting new tires

Tags: tires, mazda-6, fix-a-flat

What could cause two flat tires in quick succession after getting new tires. It does not appear to be bad luck.

I replaced all 4 tires on Friday morning.

- On Friday afternoon (same day!), I had a flat tire in my rear passenger side. I was driving on the highway and car started to get shaky. I then pulled over and noticed it was flat (10 psi).
- Really upset, I took it back to a different branch of the same company (Caliber). They replaced the tire.
- I didn't drive for two days. Two days later, I drove on the highway and it was another flat tire in the same place (rear passenger side).

Replaced by two different places (though same company), yet I still got a flat in the same place. Any ideas?

Mazda 6 (2014)

Comment: It depends on the cause of the flats. When someone gets a new roof, I avoid that street because of the chance of roofing nails.

Comment: Curious is the shop who replaced the first tire fail said what the cause was? If it was replaced, it was damaged, so was it punctured, or torn?

Comment: A common problem is corrosion around the bead seat area on the wheel.  This interferes with the tire bead seating and sealing and can allow air to leak out.  A good tire shop should carefully inspect the wheels for any signs of this and clean it off or recommend a replacement if it's beyond repair.  Perhaps this is the source of your problem as it seems that the chances of getting two bad tires in a row are slim.

Comment: @jwh20 I just received a call from them. Seems to be related to the valve stem. I'll get more details when I pick up the car today.

Comment: @jwh20 found a related question here: 
https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42547/flat-tire-right-after-replacing-all-tires-what-could-be-the-cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They found the issue. related to corrosion in the valve stem. They didn't replace it when they replaced the tires. Awful service, I'm never going back there.

Found a related question/answer here.

[Flat tire right after replacing all tires - what could be the cause?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42547/flat-tire-right-after-replacing-all-tires-what-could-be-the-cause)

> whoever changed the tires didn't use new valve stems and/or valves. They're located in the rim of the wheel, so it's entirely possible that they were overlooked They can become brittle and crack with age, just like tires, and should be replaced at every tire change. The valve could also be
> leaking, especially if it doesn't have a protective cap and has been
> exposed to the elements.